# Spark Executor STDOUT to Kubernetes STDOUT

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, logging, log4j

My spark application running inside Spark Worker outputs the executor logs to a specific file path: `"/worker_home_directory/app-xxxxxxxx/0/stdout"`

I used `log4j.properties` to redirect logs from stderr to stdout, but it seems like these are still not recognized by Kubernetes as the main STDOUT logs.

My goal is to use `kubectl logs <spark_worker_pod>` and view the Spark executor logs directly. However, my current solution seems half-baked.

How do I move the logs from `/worker_home_directory/app-xxxxxxxx/0/stdout` to Kubernetes STDOUT?

Comment: How do you deploy your application? If you deploy your application using `--master $K8s_API_SERVER` in a spark-submit call you should be automatically getting the logs in the `kubectl logs` command.